# Flutter - How to change and save an integer retrieved from SharedPreferences?

Tags: dart, flutter

I retrieve an integer from SharedPreferences and I need to sum this value with another integer, but when I run the method I get an infinite loop with the sum.

I am calling the updateScore method to get a value that was saved before in SharedPreferences then I change the value with updateScore method, I save the value in SharedPreferences with saveScore method and I show the value in a Text().

```
  int currentScore;
  final int earnedScore;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      updateScore();
      setScore();

   return....

}

Future<int> getScore() async {

    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.getInt(widget.keyNameScore);

  }

  Future<void> saveScore(int score) async{

    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setInt(widget.keyNameScore, score);

  }


  void updateScore() async{

    getScore().then((value){

      currentScore = value;

      currentScore = currentScore + earnedScore;

      saveScore(currentScore);

    });

  }


  void setScore(){

    getScore().then((value){

      setState(() {
        currentScore = value;
      });

    });

  }
```

Comment: You may not call `updateScore` or `setScore` in the body of `build`. `build` must be idempotent (must not have side-effects). You'll want to set or update the score as a result of a timer, or a user interaction, or similar. Not just because the framework happened to call `build`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to move my methods from the build to initState.